# add new field to the standard aspnet_Membership table

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I have added a new field to the standard aspnet_Membership table.

Now that it's added, how do i get or set this field by UserId?

Delete, plese.(5-8-2013)

Comment: I've cleaned this up a little. It could use more clarification from the OP, but it's probably a real question about custom data in the ASP.NET Membership provider.

Answer (score 2):

You should not change default membership table . Instead use profile fields. Following articles will help .

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/10/18/427754.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2y3fs9xs.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend to use the profile features due it have a way too dirty to store the data. Only if you need just one or two more fields, it may have sense.

Anyway, you need to attempt to document yourself a little more before ask this kind of questions...